# SE chat is completely inaccessible to keyboard-only users

Tags: bug, chat, accessibility, keyboard

[Keyboard-only access is an important part of accessibility](https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/). In my case, it's simply because my mouse has stopped working, but there are many people who rely on webpages being keyboard-only friendly to navigate the web.

Stack Exchange chat completely fails.

Some extremely basic things are *impossible* to do without a mouse. Here's a list of some things I ran into:

- replying to messages
- flagging a message
- finding a specific message's transcript link
- starring messages
- kicking users
- adding room owners
- dismissing pings
- dismissing notification bar - such as a "<user> has been kicked from <room> by <user>" notification
- clearing stars
- loading older messages

In search, removing the "said by user" or "said in room" is impossible. Clicking the "show more" for stars is also impossible to get at.

This all serves to make chat very inaccessible to keyboard-only users.

Comment: An essential thing: [SE Chat Modifications -- Keyboard navigation and commands for chat](https://stackapps.com/questions/2105/se-chat-modifications-keyboard-navigation-and-commands-for-chat) (StackApps script)

Comment: @V2Blast the question isn't about keyboard shortcuts, it's about keyboard in general. As far as I know there aren't shortcuts in chat, and even so that's not the issue, and neither does the OP request to add any shortcuts.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron: Fair enough. I've added the [keyboard] tag instead. :)